# Swift filter array of objects by objects INT! property

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, properties, int

Here's my object.

```
class TicketsCellModel: NSObject {

    var title: String?
    var text: String?
    var price: String?
    var tintColor: UIColor?
    var quantity: Int?
}
```

Here is some random data

```
var ticketCellModels: [TicketsCellModel] = {
    var cellOne = TicketsCellModel()
    cellOne.title = "Standard Entry"
    cellOne.text = "This is aa standard entry ticket, it's not sutiable for special events please see the plus ticket for that."
    cellOne.price = "£8.35"
    cellOne.tintColor = UIColor.white
    cellOne.quantity = 0

    var cellThree = TicketsCellModel()
    cellThree.title = "Standard with re-entry"
    cellThree.text = "This is a standard entry ticket but you can come and go as you please during the night."
    cellThree.price = "£8.99"
    cellThree.tintColor = UIColor.white
    cellThree.quantity = 2

    var cell6 = TicketsCellModel()
    cell6.title = "Plus Entry"
    cell6.text = "This is the plus entry ticket for special events."
    cell6.price = "£9.99"
    cell6.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 192, green: 192, blue: 192)
    cell6.quantity = 0

    var cell9 = TicketsCellModel()
    cell9.title = "VIP Entry"
    cell9.text = "Here is some more text that is to act as a description for this thing you will purchase."
    cell9.price = "£12.99"
    cell9.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 255, green: 215, blue: 0)
    cell9.quantity = 4
    return [cellOne, cellThree, cell6, cell9]
}()
```

I am now trying to produce a new array of TicketsCellModel but with only those that have quantity > 0. I am able to do the following to filter by those starting with title "S"

```
let filteredTicketCellModels = ticketCellModels.filter( { return ($0.title?.starts(with: "S") )! } )
        for item in filteredTicketCellModels {
            print("qty: \(item.title)")
        }
```

But if I tweak this to;

```
let filteredTicketCellModels = ticketCellModels.filter( { return ($0.quantity? > 0)! } )
for item in filteredTicketCellModels {
    print("qty: \(item.quantity)")
}
```

I get "Binary operator '>' cannot be appliedt to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int'". I can't find any examples of how I do this for int's

Comment: Why are these fields optional? When would you ever have a ticket without  a title, price, or quantity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a quick and safe fix, you can use the nil coalescing operator `??` to have item.quantity = 0 when it's equal to nil.

It'd look like this:

```
let filteredTicketCellModels = ticketCellModels.filter( { return ($0.quantity ?? 0 > 0)! } )
    for item in filteredTicketCellModels {
        print("qty: \(item.quantity)")
    }
```

The reason why your filtering by titles doesn't crash is because none of your optional variables contain nil. If item.title were == to nil however, that bang (!) at the end of it causes a crash upon variable access.

If titles (or any other variables within your class) are never nil, you should declare them as just `var title: String` , without the `?` at the end (which would mean you have to actually have an initializer for your object too! (which is better practice anyways :) ))

Comment: Oh! I see. I also managed to get this to fit what I am doing.


let filteredTicketCellModels = ticketCellModels.filter( { return $0.quantity != 0 } )

Comment: That approach will work, but will not filter out any quantities of nil (which it looks like you have since it was crashing upon your force-unwrapping), which I'm not sure if you want or don't want.

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit
```

First of all you don't need to inherit from `NSObject`. Also, if you don't need reference semantics, use `struct`s instead.

```
struct TicketsCellModel {
  var title: String?
  var text: String?
  var price: String?
  var tintColor: UIColor?
  var quantity: Int?
}
```

It's not really necessary to use a closure to create an `[TicketsCellModel]`. Just assign the elements directly. Since we're using `struct`s we don't need to create a separate `init`.

```
var ticketCellModels = [
  TicketsCellModel(
    title: "Standard Entry",
    text: "This is aa standard entry ticket, it's not sutiable for special events please see the plus ticket for that.",
    price: "£8.35",
    tintColor: UIColor.white,
    quantity: 0
  ),
  TicketsCellModel(
    title: "Standard with re-entry",
    text: "This is a standard entry ticket but you can come and go as you please during the night.",
    price: "£8.99",
    tintColor: UIColor.white,
    quantity: 2
  ),
  TicketsCellModel(
    title: "Plus Entry",
    text: "This is the plus entry ticket for special events.",
    price: "£9.99",
    tintColor: UIColor.white,
    quantity: 0
  ),
  TicketsCellModel(
    title: "VIP Entry",
    text: "Here is some more text that is to act as a description for this thing you will purchase.",
    price: "£12.99",
    tintColor: UIColor.white,
    quantity: 4
  )
]
```

Now, if you need to access an optional, you will have to unwrap it first. The safest way to do this is using the `if let` construct or using the [nil-coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72).

```
let filteredTicketCellModels = ticketCellModels.filter { $0.quantity ?? 0 > 0 }

print(filteredTicketCellModels)
```

In the example above there are no unknown variables during initialization, so maybe non-optional properties might be better suited. Then you don't have to unwrap anything.

[Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) adds that it is recommended that all properties be constants. The way to do this is to replace all `var`s with `let`s. If you need to change a property you can create a new object copying the properties from the old one and adding the new values to the properties that have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the two solutions that work are.

```
let filteredTicketCellModels = ticketCellModels.filter( { return ($0.quantity ?? 0 > 0) } )
```

The second is;-

```
let filteredTicketCellModels = ticketCellModels.filter( { return $0.quantity != 0 } )
```

I have also set a default value of quantity to zero.